# How to access element inside shadow root in Robot framework

Tags: iframe, robotframework, shadow-dom

I am unable to get the title that is inside the iframe and it is located inside shadow-root.

Refer the DOM:

```
div class = "test class"
 visualization-component-sdkwe234kjdbv accesstokens = <authorization-token>
  #shadow-root (open)
    iframe src ="https://www.google.com" style = border: none; box-sizing: border-box; flex-grow: 1;
     #document
        html
         head
         <title> Report Dashboard </title>
          <meta> name = viewport
```

I tried using below keywords to get the title, but I couldn't fetch it

```
Select Frame   //iframe
Get Text //title
```

can someone help me on this?

Comment: You won't be able to get into an IFRAME any way; this is not a Web Component issue.

Comment: It would help us to reproduce this if you provided valid HTML instead of pseudo-html.

Comment: Read [tour] and [mcve] and edit your post accordingly. This will help people to understand your problem and you will receive more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is one case where writing a keyword in Python instead of Robot Framework makes sense. This site explains how to access shadow elements: https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get into shadow-dom try below code, I've written it as per your html

```
Select Frame    dom:document.querySelector("visualization-component-sdkwe234kjdbv").shadowRoot.querySelector("iframe")
```

Please refer Robotframework locator strategy
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Locating%20elements