# Can not switch to iFrame using selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I encountered a challenge while trying to switch to a certain iFrame using selenium (in python if it matters)

I have this inner iFrame which resides in this weird HTML component[image: this macroponent thingy]

The iFrame is in this macroponent element: [image: the iframe is "gsft_main"]
and I cannot fetch it via selenium. I tried using `driver.switch_to_frame("gsft_main")` and also tried by using xpaths. It seems that first I need to enter this "macroponent" element before.

Any idea will be appreciated!

Comment: 1) please share your code. As a text, not as a picture. 2) If possibly share a link to that page or at least the HTML as a picture, not as a code 3) I see there are shadow roots there. This can cause difficulties. 4) `driver.switch_to_frame` no more supported. `driver.switch_to.frame('frame_name')` should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for one of the example using CSS selector to access iframe in Shadow-dom:
[How to access element inside shadow root in Robot framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70802823/how-to-access-element-inside-shadow-root-in-robot-framework/71265817#71265817)

This link has full explanation to work with shadow-dom using python, java, javascript
https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html